# What causes Package manager has died?

Tags: android

What causes this error in my application? Was generated by google admob?
I have no idea what's causing it. Eventually this occurs in my project... mainly in the api 23

```
Exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Package manager has died
android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getApplicationInfo (ApplicationPackageManager.java:263)
com.google.android.gms.common.zzo.zzy ()
com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability.zza ()
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbcp.zze ()
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbca.onConnectionSuspended ()
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbcx.onConnectionSuspended ()
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbbi.onConnectionSuspended ()
com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzaa.onConnectionSuspended ()
com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzh.handleMessage ()
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:136)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5426)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Method.java)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:515)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1268)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1084)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (NativeStart.java)
arrow_drop_down
Caused by android.os.DeadObjectException:
android.os.BinderProxy.transact (Binder.java)
android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub$Proxy.getApplicationInfo (IPackageManager.java:1863)
android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getApplicationInfo (ApplicationPackageManager.java:258)
com.google.android.gms.common.zzo.zzy ()
com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability.zza ()
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbcp.zze ()
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbca.onConnectionSuspended ()
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbcx.onConnectionSuspended ()
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbbi.onConnectionSuspended ()
com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzaa.onConnectionSuspended ()
com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzh.handleMessage ()
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:136)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5426)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Method.java)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:515)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1268)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1084)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (NativeStart.java)
```

Comment: I notice the same crash happening in my project. Package manager has died while calling PackageManager#getApplicationInfo especially on API 23 like your case as well.

Comment: No solution of it so far. i am getting in on 22 and 23 and on moto droid.